# chrome browser issue with asp.net 3.5 website

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have developed one website in asp.net 3.5. It is perfectly running in all browsers but its flickering in chrome. I am not able to find the reason. What I am doing is, I have 5 type of banners(Header,Footer,Silver,Gold and Diamond) and each one is refreshing on different time. I am using update panels. The URL of the website is http://www.allindiaeducationalhub.com.

I will be thankfull if anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of the CSS property you used there. You need to concern about the browser version and CSS support for that.

Please go through the link below, I think you will get the solution.

http://www.thewebseye.com/css-browser-compatibility.htm

**Thanks & Regards,

Subhankar**